# .NET MVC 2 RequireHttps - How to redirect www.mysite.com to mysite.com

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, ssl, https

In .NET MVC 2 you can apply the `<RequireHttps()>` attribute to make a method be secured by SSL.

```
<RequireHttps()>
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

Let's say that your SSL certificate is issued for mysite.com. If the user visits your site by entering `http://www.mysite.com`, `<RequireHttps()>` will redirect them to `https://www.mysite.com`, which would make the browser display an invalid certificate warning.

What is the best way to chop off the www. prefix when using `<RequireHttps()>` ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to always (as in when the user first goes to the www version) redirect the user to non-www version of your site.  So your requires Https attribute will work.

You can do this in IIS, see here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1154053.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm on IIS 7 and have access to the URL Rewrite module http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/.

I solved this by putting this in the web.config file of the MVC 2 application:

```
<configuration>
...
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRuleMain" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mysite\.com$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

`http://mysite.com` -> `https://mysite.com`
`http://www.mysite.com` -> `https://mysite.com`
`https://www.mysite.com` -> `https://mysite.com`

This is simple and it works, but it would still be nice to have some sort of elegant MVC only solution.