# RequireHttpsAttribute causes infinite loop on Azure+CloudFlare deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, cloudflare

I have a site hosted in Azure at http://example.azurewebsites.net and I have mapped it to http://example.com domain. I also use CloudFlare CDN. When I use RequireHttpsAttribute, the http://example.azurewebsites.net gets redirected correctly to the https URL. However, the http://example.com is repeatedly redirected to itself causing a infinite loop.

Any ideas?

Update 27-3-2017:

I looked at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144219/requirehttps-causes-redirect-loop-on-amazon-elastic-load-balancer) on X-Forwarded-Proto and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066313/net-mvc-2-requirehttps-how-to-redirect-www-mysite-com-to-mysite-com/4066487) on UrlRewrite. But neither of them solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170566-Why-isn-t-SSL-working-for-my-site-):

> if you do not have a SSL certificate on your origin server, or simply can’t use port 443 for web traffic, then you will need to use the Flexible setting in your Cloudflare dashboard. Selecting either the Full or Strict setting without a SSL certificate at your server will result in a redirect loop

As far as I know, by default, Azure App Service already enables HTTPS for your web app with a wildcard certificate for the .azurewebsites.net domain.
This certificate is not work in the custom domain, if you want to use the HTTPS protect your custom domain, you need upload or buy the certificate.

I guess, the reason why your website is always loop is you may not setting the custom domain’s certificate in the azure.
I suggest you could set your custom domain SSL and try again.

More details about how to enable SSL in azure with custom domain, you could refer to follow link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site

Comment: I was having Flexible, and selecting 'Full' did the trick. That also eliminates the need for buying a SSL certificate. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, this accepted answer is not the answer to this question. There are [known issues with some web server configurations](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000219871) that cause this. Even with a legitimate SSL Cert installed & configured in Azure for a custom domain, you still see the redirect loop in Cloudflare if you set it to Flexible. I don't know what the real answer is but I do know this accepted answer is not it.